# Need to calculate the VARIANCE of GLCM matrix of an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have calculated by Matlab the four characteristics of texture derived from the GLCM or co-occurrence matrix (entropy, contrast, correlation, energy) but in what way can the VARIANCE be calculated having the GLCM. Is there some implemented code (matlab function) for that?

Answer (score 0):

This link has details code of how to calculate GLCM variance and other statistical features in matlab.
Reference link https://www.imageeprocessing.com/2019/04/texture-measures-from-glcm-matlab-code.html

For meanX and meanY calculation
[image: MeanX and meanY calculation used later in variance calculation]
[image: Variance calculation]